# Change custom view when app running

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to make a View(extens UIView) like rectangle add it to main view.
 When app run, I can *resize* or *rotation*, *scale*... rectangle.

What should i do? I create a Rectangle_View, and try to read more tutorial in web but I can't get a solution for it.

Thank a lots

Comment: Could you explain better what you're try to do? Is your goal to resize your view programmatically? Or are you trying to get user touches and move your view accordingly? Do you want it to animate or not?

Comment: Thank for comment. I want user touches and make resize, rotate.. the rec. It like Paint soft in Windown. When you add a rec, you can resize it

Answer (score 1):

You can manage touches using these methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Remember to call `super` to forward the message to the next responder!!

Take a look at documentation about [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
I also suggest to take a look at [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) that demonstrates how to handle touches, including multiple touches and how to move multiple objects.